# Does it have any meaning to compute the $\chi^2$ and the exact Fisher test on big contingency tables

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test, many-categories

I have several datasets containing integers. I want to perform a bivariate analysis between a specific subset of variables. However, some of them have a lot of modalities. Is computing a $\chi^2$ meaningful in this case since the contingency table can be very big (e.g. >1000x1000)? What are thresholds (e.g. size of the contingency table or content) to determine if a $\chi^2$ test is still useful?
The same questions also apply for the exact Fisher test. Finally, what kind of statistical analysis can be performed if the $\chi^2$ and Fisher test cannot be applied?

**Update:**

The considered dataframes contain between 100 thousand and several million  lines. Most of them have several dozens of columns. They also belong to very different domains.

In order to provide more information, here is a *specific case-study*:
I have an anonymized medical dataframe that contains 3.5 million medical operations performed. There are about 500 different medical operations registered classified in 180 types of operations, spread over more than 100 departments and 100 cities. Although the medical operations can be classified in types and the type can be classified in medical domains, the modalities appear to be independent. The same applies for cities.

Does it make sense to compute a Chi2 between the (type of) medical operation and the cities in order to analyze the statistical dependencies between these two variables despite the large number of modalities?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but for interesting&useful answers, we need more context. First: I cannot think of a situation where full independence is an interesting hypothesis for a 1000x1000 table, there must be some structure! So: Sample size? What does row/col categories represent in the "real world"? I woud maybe start with some visualizations, correspondence analysis, ... but you really need totell us more.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I added some information to be more precise about what kind of typical operations I would like to perform and on which kind of data. Does it help?

Comment: You really need to be even more specific, large contingency tables needs something very different from simply tests of independence! which you are sure will be rejeced. What kind of structure are you interested in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to think that with such a big contingency table there must be some structure to the table, so the null hypothesis of independence is really void if interest. But the chi-square test of independence can be calculated, it is not meaningless, it just seems a waste of time. *If* you go that way, you might have problems with the chisquare approximation because of some small counts, in that case go for simulation.

But rather go directly to investigate the patterns in the table, for example starting with correspondence analysis. But there are many other possibilities, some ideas in [this paper](https://publik.tuwien.ac.at/files/PubDat_198069.pdf), maybe mosaic plots (search this site), reordering rows/columns to facilitate visual detection of patterns, visualization [a list of some relevant posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=visualization+of+very+large+contingency+tables+site:stats.stackexchange.com&safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=anl&sxsrf=ALeKk018TX2EzWID6xTD-3u3FuBoLTSwZQ:1598477470293&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis9rDO6LnrAhWmtYsKHQvADg0QrQIoAnoECAcQAw&biw=1232&bih=607&dpr=1.5), there is a lot of ideas from [the deltarho website](http://deltarho.org/).

An interesting book is *Spectral Clustering
and Biclustering
Learning Large Graphs
and Contingency Tables* by Marianna Bolla.